# Explain this algebraic manipulation

Tags: calculus, limits, fractions

The proof of the product rule for derivatives in a book I have goes like this:

$$\begin{align}
(f \cdot g) (a) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ (f \cdot g)(a + h) - (f \cdot g)(a) }{ h } \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(a + h)g(a + h) - f(a)g(a) }{ h } \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \left(  \frac{ f(a + h)[g(a +h) - g(a)]  }{h}  + \frac{ [f(a + h) - f(a) ] g(a) }{h}  \right) \\
&= ...
\end{align}$$

I can't get the second to the third step. What exactly happened in the numerator?

I mean it's a correct manipulation, but I would like to understand what kind of manipulation was done there.

Comment: You added and subtracted $f \left( a + h \right) g \left( a \right)$ and then factorized the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In analysis (in particular, in calculus proofs involving limits), it is very common to rewrite a difference $A-B$ as
$$A-B=(A-C)+(C-B),$$
which is obviously true.

In your case, this trick was applied with
$$A=f(a+h)g(a+h),\quad B=f(a)g(a),\quad C=f \left( a + h \right) g \left( a \right).$$

In fact, is also very common to rewrite a difference $AD-BE$ as
$$AD-BE=(AD-AE)+(AE-BE)=A(D-E)+E(A-B)$$
in order to apply known informations about $D-E$ and $A-B$ (which is exactly what happened in your case).